# When run unit test in vue Konva library error

Tags: vuejs3, config, vue-cli, konvajs, webpack-5

my project is vue3 (mocha + sinon) vue-cli and using konva library, if start project alway working, but only error when i was run unit test. My project just use konva (not use vue-konva)

I already add lib canvas, webpack-node-externals. If won't fix is there any way ignore konva when run unit test?
[image]